# Parsing text in R (e.g., "[1,2,3]")

Tags: r, parsing, text

I would like to convert a string like this "[1,2,3]" into a vector like this c(1,2,3) in R. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

I was only able to get rid of the quotes and brackets but I have difficulty converting the resulting character "1,2,3" into a numeric vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option is to change the `[]` to `()` and use `eval/parse`

```
eval(parse(text = paste0('c', chartr("[]", "()", "[1,2,3]" ))))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

---

Or a package solution will be using `jsonlite`

```
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON("[1,2,3]")
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is first removing `[` and `]` with `gsub` and after that split the number with `strplit` by comma like this:

```r
string = "[1,2,3]"
gsub('\\[|\\]', '', string)           
#> [1] "1,2,3"
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub('\\[|\\]', '', string), ',')))
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The first alternative is base R.  It removes square brackets and then scans in what is left use sep = ",".

The next alternative captures each consecutive run of digits and applies `as.numeric` to it using `strapply` in gsubfn which inputs into the function given as second argument each match to the regular expression and outputs the return values of the function.

The above two have the advantage that it would be easy to modify them for variations of the input format.

The third alternative uses the fact that the input is in JSON format and is not really flexible to variations (although perhaps one could transform it) but it is the shortest for this particular format. @akrun pointed out that he had already posted the last one.

```
x <- "[1,2,3]"

scan(text = gsub("[][]", "", x), sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)
## [1] 1 2 3

library(gsubfn)
strapply(x, "\\d+", as.numeric, simplify = c)
## [1] 1 2 3

library(jsonlite)
fromJSON(x)
## [1] 1 2 3
```